# Is using a class (not interface) as a type is a bad practice for parametrized class?

Tags: java

I have code similar to this

```
public class NewClass extends GenericClass<SomeClass>
```

but I'm not sure if it is really a bad practice, may be it should be done like this

```
public class NewClass extends GenericClass<SomeInterface>
```

or am I just making it up, and there's no such convention and my suggestion is only based on general *interface good/class bad* logic?
I couldn't find anything about this, only info on generics, that may be not that much true in this case.

Comment: It would depend on the context, I think, which means no it's not universally bad practice.

Comment: If anything, this may be asked about the declaration of `GenericClass` itself. And even in that case, I think, that would only be significant if the parameter type parameter of `GenericClass` is bounded. Otherwise, this is up to the subclass and whether the type argument is an interface or a class makes no meaningful difference (as far as good practices related to just that)

Comment: not a bad practice but using Interface your class is totally decoupled from any concrete class. So, using class is not a bad practice but the use of Interfaces is a good practice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a bad practice, for my opinion, because the generic type may be either a `Class` or an `Interface`, accordingly to the purpose it is defined to be.

```
public class NewClass extends GenericClass<SomeClass>
```

this can be interpreted as "extends a generic class that uses a specific class or subclass": so that parameter class must have some members/methods.

```
public class NewClass extends GenericClass<SomeInterface>
```

this can be interpreted as "extends a generic class that **implements** a specific Interface or subInterface": so that parameter class must implements methods defined in that Interface and therefore `NewClass` can invoke them securely assuming that those methods are available.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time, but I make my choices pragmatically. More specifically, I might do something like this:

```
public FooArray extends ArrayList<Foo> {
    public void loadFromFile(String filename) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You quite literally can't do something like that with an interface unless you also pass in a factory. Now, are there other ways to accomplish the same thing? Certainly. But I find this code clear, useful, and very easy to maintain.